# Can't upload Java app to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, command-prompt

I'm trying to upload Vosao CMS to Google App Engine. After entering ...appcfg.cmd update ... in Windows command prompt it requested email, then password but I can't enter a single symbol after password request! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least on Linux, your password is intentionally not echoed (as a security measure).  I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same on Windows.  Have you tried typing it and pressing Enter even though you can't see what you type?

Comment: @DarshanComputing that would be a good answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As a security measure, the uploader does not echo your password as you type it.  Carefully type your password anyway, then press Enter.